# Full year calendar widget

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, perl

I'm looking for a calendar widget kind of like the following:
http://www.calendarlabs.com/online-calendar.php

I wouldn't mind finding one as jquery or PHP or Perl would be fine.

Comment: What exactly do you want your widget to look like and functionality to have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I think I'll have to go w/ a "roll your own", not a big deal.  Thanks for the answers / advice.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't quite a full year calendar, but it is a month/week/day calendar:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

I've used it before, and with minor tweaking it can be skinned however you want. It's very solid.

Comment: I've used fullcalendar, unfortunately it's not what I need.  As for the rating, believe it or not, I didn't know about "accepting" answers, I'm going through and accepting all I've used.

Comment: @Paul: nice work! It's understandable...SO's UI isn't immediately obvious to newer users :-]

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery-ui.version.js (just dowload the latest version) you  : just visit jquery.com, the example show picking on date, datepicker() function and it shows 
a month calendar but it is easy to customise to have full year.

Good luck

Comment: I thought about that, however in the end it's not what I'm really looking for.  Unfortunately I think I'll have to roll my own.  Not a big deal.